# IOS Swift How can i use grid animation Value?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, grid

I wanna using Grid easeInOut animation but swift sending warning IOS 15.0
So, What value should I write here

I dont know how to use it

so please i need someone help

'''

```
struct MysegmentView: View {
    
    var dummyDataArray = MyModel.dummyDataArray
    
    @State var selectedLayoutType : LayoutType = .table
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            
            Picker(selection: $selectedLayoutType, label: Text(".."), content: {
                ForEach(LayoutType.allCases, id: \.self, content: {
                    layoutType in
                    switch layoutType{
                        case .table:
                            Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                        case .grid:
                            Image(systemName: "rectangle.grid.2x2")
                        case .triple:
                            Image(systemName: "circle.grid.3x3")
                       
                    }
                })
            }).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: selectedLayoutType.columns, content: {
                    ForEach(dummyDataArray) { dataItem in
                        Rectangle().frame(height: 100)
                    }
                    
                }).animation(.easeInOut, value: ??)
```

'''

Comment: value that you need to track and do animating based on it.

Comment: i know value's meaning but i dont know how value i writing this

Answer (score 0):

The new `animation` modifier is meant to take a value so it animates the changes that are caused by that value. If you use the old modifier, you'll notice that every change will be animated.

What value should you provide? It depends on what you want to animate. If you want to animate the drawing of the grid, simply pass in `dummyDataArray` as your value.

Comment: thank u so much but i wrote value 'dummyDataArray' but its not showing any animation , there's just change its like nothing animation